# Regex mathching strings that exclude and include two strings

Tags: python, regex

Take two strings, for example aaaa and bbbb, I want a to find a regex that mathches every string containing aaaa as a substring but at the same time don't contain bbbb.

Comment: `r'^(?!.*bbbb).*aaaa'`

Answer (score 1):

```
test = ['staaaap', 'nomatchaaaaabbbb', 'matchyaaaabbb']

for s in test:
    m = re.match(r'(?!.*bbbb.*).*aaaa.*', s)
    if m:
        print('{} match: {}'.format(s, m.group(0)))
    else:
        print('{} no match'.format(s))
```

Output:

```
staaaap match: staaaap
nomatchaaaaabbbb no match
matchyaaaabbb match: matchyaaaabbb
```